# How set my Illustrator document to be 150 dpi?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, dpi

I am creating something for print that will be `160.472"w x 89.764"h`.  I'm not sure where to set these dimensions in Illustrator and set the dpi.

Comment: When you save your illustration to send to print (PDF I guess?), those settings can be made in the Save As menu. In that scenario, you don't have to change your work area.

Answer (score 5):

Under "Effect"-tab you're able to enhance the documents resolution in "Document Raster Effect Settings" if I've translated it correctly from Dutch...

Comment: This setting alters the resolution of **raster EFFECTS** and has no bearing on document size nor placed raster images within AI.

Answer (score 3):

Everything you need to set is in the **New Document** window. This image shows all the correct settings based upon your question:

[image]

Comment: is there any way to change DPI (raster Effects) once document is created?

Comment: @Vikas `Effect > Document Raster Effects Settings...` Note that this changes raster **effects**, i.e. Effect > drop shadow, Effect > outer glow, etc.. its does **not** alter any placed or embedded raster image files, in *any* way.

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator do not have DPI setting, because it is vector editor. BUT each raster image putted into artboard has it. Please refer to my screenshot to see the effective DPI (PPI) for selected raster image.

[image]

You need to control that your images would not be less 150 dpi (ppi). If larger - it is ok.

Comment: But where can I set the overall document size?

Comment: Size of artboard can be specified due creation of document or Alt+Ctrl+P and Edit Artboard (at the top you will see)

Comment: Illustrator does have a DPI setting, Document Raster Effects Settings. This setting will effect any effects and images that are rasterized. Especially important when it comes to outputting your document. If you find your workflow slowing you can lower this setting while working, and raise it before output. It will speed things up a bit.

Comment: This actual to transparency and effects.. only .. as well as 300 dpi for rasterize the transparency is not improve the quality of 72 dpi image in document.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set DPI after your work si done - when exporting for print: save as copy - pdf - and there is place to set your desired resolution. Don't forget - it applies only for raster images.